# How might I clear a hiddenfield value when the page is refresh in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, hiddenfield

How can I clear the value of an `asp:HiddenField` control when the user hits the refresh button in the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the load event (`Page_Load`, `OnLoad`) set `hiddenVariableControl.Value = String.Empty`.

If you are capturing this hidden variable's value for another event, you could do the following in the load event:

```
if( !Page.IsPostBack ) 
{
  hiddenVariableControl.Value = String.Empty;
}
```

This sets the value of the hidden variable to a blank string on refreshes, but postbacks (like a button event) would keep the value.

Comment: hai,
    I will use that hidden field in a button click event... As you know when a click event is triggred Page load will be called at that time that hidden field will have no value if i set hiddenVariableControl.Value = String.Empty... Any option for this

Comment: when the user hits refresh button on the browser i want to clear the hidden field